# Método me elimina todo el contenido del archivo

Tags: java, poo, eclipse, herencia, polimorfismo

Tengo este método para eliminar una línea del archivo, que es para seleccionar una placa escribiendola y si la placa es igual al dato en la posición 0 que es el lugar donde se guardan las placas entonces continue y luego que siga escribiendo, en otras palabras lo que quiero es sobreescribir todo el texto pero esta vez sin el que eliminé lo que pasa es me que eliminar todos los vehiculos y no solo es que selecciono. adjunto mi código.

```
    public Vehiculo eliminarVehiculo(String placa) throws IOException {
       
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(Ruta.RUTAVEHICULOS));
    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(Ruta.RUTAVEHICULOS, true));
    String linea;
    while((linea = br.readLine()) != null) {
        if(linea.equalsIgnoreCase(placa)) {
            continue;
        } // If
        bw.write(linea);
    } // While
    return null;
} // Eliminar Vehiculos
    while(linea != null) {
        datos = linea.split(",");
        if(placa.equalsIgnoreCase(datos[0])) {
            continue;
        } // If
        bw.write(linea);
    } // While
    return null;
} // Eliminar Vehiculos
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usa el `valor` true para indicar que se anexará información (append):

```
new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("myfile.txt", true)));
```

El constructor :

[FileWriter(String fileName, boolean append)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html)

determina lo siguiente

> Construye un objeto FileWriter al que se le da un nombre de archivo
> con un booleano que indica si se anexan o no los datos escritos.

en tu código sería:

```
  BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(Ruta.RUTAVEHICULOS, true));
```

Comment: lo hice pero se encicla la interfaz y se queda ahí pegada

Comment: Debo cerrarlo desde el botón e stop del ide porque no cierra ni nada

Comment: ya actualicé el código lo adjunto a la pregunta

Comment: El problema es el while  while(linea != null)  , debe ser  while ((linea = br.readLine()) != null){  , estas tratando de abrir el archivo , eliminar la placa y obtener un archivo actualizado verdad?

Comment: Si eso es lo que intento

Comment: pero arriba abajo de los buffered tengo linea = br.readline();

Comment: ok perfecto si, tenías razón no se actualizaba el valor de linea, listo ya lo cambié ahora el problema es que no se elimina :/

Comment: actualicé nuevamente el código

Comment: Lo que busco es que me borre toda la línea eso es lo que quiero

Comment: y que me haga un archivo nuevo sin esa línea

Comment: Buenas, ya te funciona? porque veo 2 whiles y uno de ellos fuera del método eliminarVehiculo

Comment: Debes de usar solo 1 while!